# How to check if any of the items satisfy certain criteria in Swift collection?

Tags: swift

Is there a way in Swift to check if **any** of the items satisfy certain criteria?

For example, given an array of integers I would like to see if it contains even numbers (this code will not work):

```
[1, 2, 3].any { $0 % 2 == 0 } // true
[1, 3, 5].any { $0 % 2 == 0 } // false
```

#### My imperfect solution

I am currently using the following approach:

```
let any = [1, 3, 5].filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }.count > 0
```

I don't think it is very good.

1. It is a bit verbose.
2. The filter closure argument will be called for all items in the array, which is unnecessary.

Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the method `contains` to accomplish what you want. It is better than filter because it does not need a whole iteration of the array elements:

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3]
if numbers.contains(where: { $0 % 2 == 0 }) {
    print(true)
}
```

or **Xcode 10.2+** https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/3127688-ismultiple

```
if numbers.contains(where: { $0.isMultiple(of: 2) }) {
    print(true)
}
```

Comment: Excellent, I did not know `contains` can take a closure argument.

Comment: issue here is we can't access the items which satisfied our criteria. Instead of printing true, I would like to access those items

Comment: @Abdullah So you need a `filter`. If you need only the first occurrence you can use `first(where: predicate)`

Answer (score 10):

Correct answer updated for Swift 5:

```
[1, 2, 3].contains(where: { $0 % 2 == 0 })
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4.2/Xcode 10 you can use the method `allSatisfy` of class `Array` to solve your problem. Here is an example:

```
let a = !([1, 2, 3].allSatisfy { $0 % 2 != 0 })
print(a) // true
let b = !([1, 3, 5].allSatisfy { $0 % 2 != 0 })
print(b) // false
```

If your current version of Xcode is prior to 10.0 you can find the function `allSatisfy` in [Xcode9to10Preparation](https://github.com/RomanPodymov/Xcode9to10Preparation). You can install this library with CocoaPods.

Comment: While your example does work, if you use this be careful about the double negative here. This works because the result of `allSatisfy()` **and** the test in the closure are both inverted. In my opinion it's more readable to use `contains()` or to roll your own extension.

Answer (score -3):

this may help

```
func find(value coinSymbol: String, in array: [CoinModel]) -> CoinModel? {
    for (_, value) in array.enumerated() {
        if value.symbol.uppercased() == coinSymbol {
            return value
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: What you need here is collection's method `first(where predicate:)`. In you case `func find(value coinSymbol: String, in array: [CoinModel]) -> CoinModel? {` `array.first { $0.symbol.caseInsensitiveCompare(coinSymbol) == .orderedSame }`